# How to make music sheet of these two measures in music21

Tags: python, music21

I have two adjacent measures here:

[image]

My problem is how to make this piece of music with music21 python package.

```
from music21 import *
s = stream.Stream();
n = note.Note('C5',quarterLength = 0.5);
s.append(n);
n = note.Note('A4',quarterLength = 0.5);
s.append(n);
n = note.Note('C5',quarterLength = 0.5);
s.append(n);
n = note.Note('A4',quarterLength = 0.5);
s.append(n);
n = note.Note('C5',quarterLength = 0.5);
s.append(n);
n = note.Note('A4',quarterLength = 0.5);
s.append(n);
n = note.Note('C5',quarterLength = 0.5);
s.append(n);
n = note.Note('A4',quarterLength = 0.5);
s.append(n);
c = note.Note('E4',quarterLength = 8);
s.insertIntoNoteOrChord(0, c);
s.show('lily.pdf')
```

The error coming was

> s.insertIntoNoteOrChord(0, c);
> music21.exceptions21.StreamException: more than one element found at
> the specified offset

How can I rectify the error?

Edit:

```
from music21 import note,stream
s = stream.Measure();
c = note.Note('E4',quarterLength = 8);
s.insert(0, c)
n = note.Note('C5',quarterLength = 0.5);
s.append(n);
n = note.Note('A4',quarterLength = 0.5);
s.append(n);
n = note.Note('C5',quarterLength = 0.5);
s.append(n);
n = note.Note('A4',quarterLength = 0.5);
s.append(n);
n = note.Note('C5',quarterLength = 0.5);
s.append(n);
n = note.Note('A4',quarterLength = 0.5);
s.append(n);
n = note.Note('C5',quarterLength = 0.5);
s.append(n);
n = note.Note('A4',quarterLength = 0.5);
s.append(n);

s.show('lily.pdf')
```

is giving output as

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your command `s.insertIntoNoteOrChord(0, c);` is unnecessary. You're trying to insert the tied whole notes into the first measure, not into a note or chord. You should just `s.insert(0, c)`.

Also, there are ways to batch insert, see the docs for `Stream.insert()`.

EDIT -- for example:

```
from music21 import note,stream
s = stream.Stream()  # sorry, your instinct to use a stream was probably good

n = note.Note('C5',quarterLength = 0.5)
s.append(n)
n = note.Note('A4',quarterLength = 0.5)
s.append(n)
n = note.Note('C5',quarterLength = 0.5)
s.append(n)
n = note.Note('A4',quarterLength = 0.5)
s.append(n)
n = note.Note('C5',quarterLength = 0.5)
s.append(n)
n = note.Note('A4',quarterLength = 0.5)
s.append(n)
n = note.Note('C5',quarterLength = 0.5)
s.append(n)
n = note.Note('A4',quarterLength = 0.5)
s.append(n)
c = note.Note('E4',quarterLength = 8)
s.insert(0, c)
out1 = s.makeVoices()
out2 = out1.makeNotation()
out2.show('lily.pdf')
```

[image]

Much better with `.show('musicxml.pdf')`:

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific: what do you mean by did not work? Also, I can offer some more tips. To represent this correctly, `s` should be a `stream.Measure`, not a `stream.Stream` unless you are going to makeNotation afterward, but speaking of that, you should run `.makeVoices()` or even `.makeNotation()` before attempting to show('lily.pdf'). This step can be skipped if you run `.show('musicxml.pdf')` which runs makeNotation for you. What version of music21 are you on?

Comment: I have tried with measure,makeVoices and makeNotation. Still I did not get the sheet I want.

Comment: Got it, sorry if my reply sounded short, I was over-caffeinated. :-D

Comment: From your image you just posted, you are lacking voices. To have two overlapping layers in a measure that sound at the same time you must have voices. It's possible lilypond output does not support voices, that's why I suggested 'musicxml.pdf'. But it would help in debugging to find out why you don't have voices after running makeNotation. You can post the ouput of s.show('text') to see what containers you have.

Comment: Ah! Your second version shows yourself appending notes after you insert the first note. That's why they're appearing one after the other. You could either append all the eighth notes and then go back and insert the whole note at 0 which was essentially my first advice.